# node.js https cross-origin request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, https, cross-domain

I'm making a request to HTTPS server set up on node.js like below, and I'm getting:

*'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://ku6sn0zj.apps.lair.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.'* error.

Have I not **set up the headers** correctly? There is no indication on the server that a request has been attempted when I put a `console.log` in the beginning of the callback. Other ways I tried was setting headers in **writeHead(statusCode, {here go them headers});**

```
var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://ku6sn0zj.apps.lair.io'); // client address
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        req.on('data', function(data) {
            data = data + '';
            data = data.split('&');
            if(data[0].slice(7) == 'login'){
                var credentials = {};
                credentials.username = data[1].slice(9);
                credentials.password = data[2].slice(9);
                game.foo(credentials.username, credentials.password, function(err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else if (response === true) { //password match
                        var token = foo()
                        res.writeHead(200);
                        res.end(token);
```

this goes on, but it isn't all that important.
Now, I'm sending a request using AJAX from a node express app like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://94jzlodc.apps.lair.io', //server address
            data: {
                action: 'login',
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            statusCode: {*here comes response handling*}
})
```

http server listens on port 8000,
and express app is on default 3000,

[oi68.tinypic.com/15gxg0x.jpg](http://oi68.tinypic.com/15gxg0x.jpg) those are the **headers**. not specifying ports in the app settings is the only way I even get a response header.

Comment: What response headers do you see when the request is received?

Comment: i updated the post, not sure if u got the memo from that. I would greatly appreciate some help. one guy in thr deleted answers comment suggested there might be a proxy intefering in ther sourcelair infrastructure. should I perhaps inquire their support about that?